# simple rounding down decimal places

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple function to round down a number based on a certain number of decimal places by using the built-in round function and subtracting the last decimal by 1 if it rounds up.

```
def rounddown(number, places):
    rounded = round(number, places)
    if rounded > number:
        string = '1'
        for x in range(places):
            string = string + '0'
        return rounded - (1/float(string))
    else:
        return rounded
```

my problem is sometimes the results end up being a number like this:

```
rounddown(4.555756, 5)

4.555750000000001
```

Could someone explain to me exactly what is going on here?  I think it may have something to do with floating point math inaccuracy?

Thank you

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is basically Floating point operations ,to avoid the problem
Please use the decimal library as shown below

```
from decimal import Decimal
def rounddown(number, places):
    rounded = round(number, places)
    if rounded > number:
        string = '1'
        for x in range(places):
            string = string + '0'
        return Decimal(str(rounded))-1/Decimal(string)
    else:
        return rounded
```